# How to set SeverSide in dynamic column in jquery datacolumn?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have created a data table for the dynamic column and here is the code for the data table.

```
<table id="tag" class="display table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.Select((value, i) => new { i, value}))
                        {
                            <th id=@(item.i+1)>@item.value.Category</th>
                        }
                        <th id="@(Model.Count()+1)">Simulation Name</th>
                        <th id="@(Model.Count()+2)">Patient Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
 </table>
```

and the javascript code for the dynamic data table is

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#tag").DataTable({
                "aLengthMenu": [[5,10, 25, 50, 75, -1], [5,10, 25, 50, 75, "All"]],
                "iDisplayLength": 5,
                serverSide: true,
                stateSave: true,
                search: true,
                ajax: {
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: 'GetFilteredPatientTagss',
                    success: function (d) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < d.requestedRecords.length; i++) {
                            var result = Object.values(d.requestedRecords[i]);
                            $('#tag').DataTable().row.add(result).draw(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Here I have done serverSide is true, If I set  `server-side: false` then the dataTable is fine, and search, dropdown and pagination are all from the client-side, but when I set `serverSide: true` it goes for infinite loop in the API and no data is displayed in the data table. I need to search and paginate in the data table from the server-side in this dynamic column(where there is no fixed number of columns). How Can I do this?

Comment: Do not use `ajax.success` inside a DataTable. Use [`dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) instead. As it says on that page: _"the success option of ajax should not be altered - DataTables uses it internally to execute the table draw when the data load is complete."_.

Comment: Also, there should be no need to write data to your table using `row.add()` inside your DataTable definition. If you point `dataSrc` to the right part of your JSON response, that is all you need to do. DataTables will handle iterating over the JSON and loading the table.

Comment: @andrewjames thanks it worked successfully with data-src it worked, but when I go to the next page by pagination or increase dropdown, the data is added instead of replacing, how can I fix that?

Comment: You can [edit] your question to show us your new approach.